# How to use H.265/HEVC C++ decoder in C# project

Tags: c#, c++, ffmpeg, hevc, h.265

I need to write a C# application that uses any open-source video decoding library that supports 4K resolution (H.265/HEVC or VP9). **The problem is that they are written in C or C++ and I dont know how to use them in C#.**

**Idea:** Would it be able to compile them into a .dll for use in C#?

---

The following **open source libraries** I found are:

- OpenHEVC https://github.com/OpenHEVC/openHEVC
- libde265 https://github.com/strukturag/libde265
- FFMPEG http://git.1f0.de/gitweb?p=ffmpeg.git

Thanks for reading!

Comment: There is a wrapper for FFMPEG, try it : http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/

Comment: The wrapper doesn't contain the latest version and doesn't support H.265 decoding (only up to H.264) since it's a recent feature. Proof http://www.ffmpeg-activex.com/formats.html

Comment: Then, ask the author, if he has the latest version with H265, or you can extend it by your own ? It's not an easy job to write a wrapper.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft Media Foundation supports H.265 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt218785(v=vs.85).aspx.  It's a COM library, not that that has stopped c# programmers before.